# Traversing list index using for loop | unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'tuple' in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, syntax-error, traversal

```
for tuple in result :
    if result[i-2][3] > result[i-1][3] and result[i-2][1] > result[i][1] :
        print('Success')   
        i = i + 1
```

Suppose :
`result` is a `list of tuples`:

```
result = [('a','b',2,3),('p','q',4,5),.....,('l','m',7,9)]
```

Now I want to do a list traversal my above code is working but I want to now start another for loop inside this for loop and traverse the next items of the list using another variable say `n`. So the code would somewhat look like

```
n = 2
for tuple in result :
     for n in result :
         if result[i-n][3] > result[i-1][3] and result[i-n][1] > result[i][1] :
             print('Success')
     n = n + 1
i = i + 1
```

But now i get an error like `Unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'tuple'`. So i want to know what is the reason for this as to why `i-2` wouldn't be same as `i-n` in this case???

Also how can I solve it if I have to traverse the next items also in the list?

Thanks

Comment: We do NOT see where you defice `ì` - but `n` is taken from your list of tuples (`for n in result :`).  You can not deduct a tuple from `i` ...

Comment: few mistakes - `tuple` should not be used for your variable names - its a dedicated keyword in python.  where is `i` ? you are simply using `result[i-n]`   we cannot see where is `i` .

Comment: i is used as an iterator for the first loop which is an integer i = 0 and then i = i + 1 but i came to know my mistake -  the second loop should not be for n in result but rather for n in range(len(result)).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because n is a tuple object not an integer. In first iteration value of n is ('a', 'b', 2,3) not 2. In each iteration value of n is changing from tuple to tuple.

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake the second for loop should not have been for n in result but it rather should have been for n in range(2:)

But thanks i corrected the mistake and it worked.

I know it was lame but i am new to this coding world of python :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all its smart to avoid using the word tuple in your code (like using list, str or int in your code):
https://visualgit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/naming_convention.html

It is not completely clear to me what you want that your code does? Because it looks like you want to compare integers(numbers) with strings(text) which would eventually also lead to an error.

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake the second for loop should not have been for n in result but it rather should have been for n in range(2:)

But thanks i corrected the mistake and it worked.

I know it was lame but i am new to this :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i made a mistake the second for loop should not have been for n in result but it rather should have been for n in range(2:)

But thanks i corrected the mistake and it worked.

I know it was lame but i am new to this :)